# android mapFragment nullpointer exception

Tags: android, exception

I am implementing an app which uses GPS Location data , with a mapFragment integration. Inside the fragment, i am instantiating the mapFragment as this:

```
val mapFragment =
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(com.example.sensorsapp.R.id.map_fragment) as com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment?
mapFragment!!.getMapAsync(this)
```

I am getting the exception mentioned bellow:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.sensorsapp.Fragments.MapFragment.fetchLocation$lambda-1
```

For some reason it fails to initialize the map object. What is the reason for this?

Comment: not sure why you've added the dictionary tag to this, probably you meant to add something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Cast the map fragment to `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment` and make sure you retrieve the mapFragment in `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated()`

```
val mapFragment =
    childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(com.example.sensorsapp.R.id.map_fragment) as SupportMapFragment?
mapFragment?.let{it.getMapAsync(this)}
```

Comment: Tried it, still i am getting the same error.

Comment: this code seems to be nullsafe as far as i can tell, so if you're still getting the same error, it's probably coming from somewhere else ? is there enough code in your post so that we can recreate the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

More code from the application:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    fetchLocation()
}
```

fetchLocation() is the function where the mapFragment is instantiated.

Within the activity layout, the framelayout that contains the fragment:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonActionRelLayout">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: set the name of fragment to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'